# Программирование для науки

Tags: работа

Как ни крути, но мы программисты любим учится, изучать что-то новое и т.д., вот и меня безумно тянет к науке! Сейчас работаю программистом на PHP, возможно в скором времени перейду полностью на C#, и нравится мне безумно программировать, но обычно это одно и тоже рекурсия за рекурсией, типичные задание и т.д., не приносящие удовольствия, только деньги...

Может я покажусь психом в некоторой мере, но я хочу программировать разные научные штуки(не знаю как назвать даже), т.е. для науки.

Во-первых это интересно, и очень познавательно...но как начать? Писать код который об числит какую-нибудь формулу не очень то интересно.

А вот какие научные вычисления можно проводить? И поможет ли мне такой опыт в будущем поступить за границу в университет?

Comment: > я хочу программировать разные научные штуки для науки

Ох, лучше не надо! Любите науку платонически!

Comment: Ели для науки, то никакого PHP и C#. Только Fortran, только хардкор.

Comment: Почему только фортран? Он, конечно, широко используется в научных вычислениях, но не только он. И С/С++, и перл, и питон, и джава и многое другое.

Comment: Да ладно вам - че накинулись на пацана. Fortran давно уже не в почете - все научники уже давно пересели на C/C++

Comment: @Barmaley Откуда разведданные?

Comment: @Barmaley, фортран как пользовали, так и пользуют. В той области, к которой я сейчас имею отношение - климатология и физика атмосферы - наверное, процентов 70 кода в мире пишется на фортране.

Comment: @alexlz, @mikillskegg: конечно, фортран используется - столько алгоритмов, библиотек уж написано. Но если раньше преподавали для научников только фортран (а еще раньше и Алгол - был такой язык), то сейчас С/С++ входит в обязательную программу. В той области откуда я (гидродинамика) - уж 2/3 сидят на C

Comment: @Barmaley, я сам все в лаборатории перевожу на С++. Но приходят ребятки с географического факультета МГУ, а им ТОЛЬКО фортран и преподают.

Comment: @mikillskegg А какой фортран? Язык-то развивается. Если f77 -- так тут многие моложе этого языка. @Barmaley "а ещё раньше и Алгол" -- это у нас. Фортран появился раньше, только вот в СССР писали в первую очередь компиляторы с международного языка алгол-60, а уж американский фортран начал проникать позже.

Comment: @alexlz, не очень четкий вопрос. Пишут в мире новые программы в основном на 98 или 2003, хотя некоторые старики пишут еще на 77 (сам таких знаю). Преподают в МГУ, кажется, фортран 98.

Comment: @mikillskegg ну на нечёткий вопрос был дан чёткий ответ. А вот переводить лаборатории на C++ не боязно? Новички на C++ могут таких вычислений написать -- никакой памяти не хватит, если поперегружают методы/операторы так, что на каждый чих будет копия толстой матрицы создаваться...

Comment: @alexlz после common блоков в фортране уже ничего не страшно :)

Comment: @mikillskegg странно, во времена совка географам вычисления не доверяли... Только физики и математики. Млин совсем уже страну до ручки довели! :)

Comment: @Barmaley Чем Вас common-блоки-то напугали? Они не размножаются, сидят себе тихо. В карте памяти линкера их видно. Структурному программированию противоречат -- так и на C/C++ extern'ов можно понавтыкать.

Answer (score 6):

> типичные задание и т.д., не приносящие удовольствия, только деньги...

олимпиадные задачки никто не отменял

> Во-первых это интересно, и очень познавательно...но как начать?

поставить себе задачу и следовать к её реализации, в наше время информация не так уж труднодоступна: гугл, треккеры с книгами, данный ресурс

> А вот какие научные вычисления можно проводить

нейронные сети и прочий ИИ, моделирование сложных структур - молекулы белка, ДНК, РНК, моделирование сложных ситуаций - Большой Взрыв, например, или что-то социально-экономическое - полный запрет торрентов и реакция различных групп населения на это

> И поможет ли мне такой опыт в будущем поступить за границу в университет?

если вы будете уметь это делать, вам учиться будет нечему

Comment: Последний пункт верно подметили :)

Comment: @Error, последний пункт - такой же загон, как и предыдущий абзац.

Comment: обоснованный и объективный коммент, по-больше бы таких

Comment: @Spectre, ваши карикатурные представления о научных задачах тянут на сцены из телесериалов в лучшем случае. А супермену и высшее образование не нужно, он и так всё знает :-)

Comment: вызнаете более точные определения для 

>разные научные штуки

Comment: Я-то знаю и поэтому не тороплюсь отвечать [:-)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGq9pyiDqHE)

Comment: эх, как не хватает возможности минусовать комментарии.

Comment: можно, но муторно это

Comment: @Spectre расскажи-ка как муторно?

Comment: @Shrek, возможно @Spectre имел в виду преобразовать комментарий в ответ, заминусовать, а потом опять перевести в комментарий.

Comment: О, еще кто-то спалил эту штуку :)

Comment: у этого метода есть недостаток - стоит плюсануть заминусованный коммент, минус снимается, но если убрать плюс, минус не возвращается.

Answer (score 4):

У меня есть ответ. Даже больше - просьба. Сделай что-то вроде [DMM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Molecular_Matter) ([видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAnXolinMPE) [для](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqauZTAlJF4) [затравки](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkHzKUrp-fs)), UNIX-совместимое и с открытыми исходниками, разумеется. Тут тебе и матан (метод конечных элементов), и наука (правдоподобная эмуляция сред для виртуальных опытов), и даже развлечения (крутая физика в играх за бесплатно!). После такого, думаю, любой универ примет с радостью.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Как правило, программировать для науки (я бы скорее назвал инженерными расчетами) означает численное решение системы нелинейных уравнений. Типичные примеры: уравнения Навье-Стокса (аэродинамика, гидродинамика, прогноз погоды), уравнения Максвелла (электродинамика), уравнения Шредингера (квантовая механика, квантовая химия).

Прочтите для начала какой-нибудь учебник Самарского - численные методы. Если интересно, значит можно и дальше заниматься. Если не зажигает - так и быть идите дальше по кривой дорожке PHP :)

Если честно, зарубежом вычметодА, не в большом почете - там всегда были мощные машины и народ привык все решать методом грубой силы. У нас в силу постоянной нехватки машинных ресурсов, все больше мозгами делали - потому по вычметодАм мы впереди планеты всей.

Comment: ОП же сказал - формулы ему скучно. А задорновская ремарка про численные методы с тридевятых царствах несколько сомнительна.

Comment: Тогда рецепт -- Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics
(http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicm/) Книга о том, что может получиться при внимательном отношении к формулам (у самого, правда, почитать руки-ноги не доходят)

А из того, во что играют молодые научные массы -- http://www.sagemath.org/

Comment: @karmadro4 вычметоды к формулам мало имеют отношения - это алгоритмы. Ну а касательно "а ля Задорнов" - как ни странно это именно так. Вычметода были развиты еще во времена проектирования атомной бомбы - там без них вообще никак.

Comment: Простой пример: метод обращения 3-х диагональной матрицы - по русски называется "progonka", трудоемкость растет линейно с ростом размерности матрицы. За бугром народ обращает "в лоб" чуть ли не методом Крамера - трудозатраты растут квадратично размерности матрицы. А зачем париться? http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002199917890150X

Answer (score 2):

[@johniek_comp](/users/5557/johniek_comp), Вы сначала для себя **досконально** определите, **что такое наука**. А потом станет понятно, какие штуки для нее можно программировать и какие языки нужны.

Кстати, некоторые люди  математику, например, наукой не считают. Другие абсолютно уверены, что медицина это не наука, а ремесло.

А Вы над этим задумывались ?

Comment: Минусну, а) есть четкие критерии, что такое наука, а что - нет б) они останутся таковыми вне зависимости от того, что вы, ОП или сам Василий Пупкин себе по этому поводу напридумываете.

> Кстати, некоторые люди математику, например, наукой не считают.

источник? Байку про Нобеля только не пересказывайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Четкие критерии ? Это то, что в энциклопедии (например) написано ?

Вы безусловно не согласитесь, но я скажу, что критерии научности субъективны. Другими словами разные люди (в разное время) могут относить к науке разные области деятельности.

Comment: Почему же? Соглашусь, но не субъективностью критериев научности, а с развитием объективных критериев. Однако, научным методом нельзя опрокинуть всю методологию науки, сделав, скажем, алхимию наукой, а математику - лженаукой. Процесс развития невозможно повернуть вспять, как и нельзя "закрыть" какое-либо открытие. Опровергнуть можно, но не закрыть. К чему это всё? К тому что нельзя отталкиваться от "науки для себя".

Comment: Да дело даже не в том, что такое наука, а в том, что у молодого человека есть желание заниматься чем-то по-настоящему серьезным, но еще много ветра в голове. Надо учиться, и тогда все станет на свои места.

Comment: Потом, говорить о "научном программировании" довольно сложно. Наук много, они в разной степени математизированы и везде своя специфика использования вычислительной техники.

Comment: IMHO наука это изучение **устройства природы** (в т.ч. и внутреннего мира человека или общества (они ведь являются частью природы)).

--

Поэтому программа, помогающая узнать что-то **новое** из этой области будет "научной". А вот программа, вычисляющая оптимальную форму спускаемого аппарата - нет. Хотя последняя тоже может быть весьма  интересной.

Answer (score 1):

> И поможет ли мне такой опыт в будущем
> поступить за границу в университет?

А зачем? У нас очень хорошая школа. Поступайте в МГУ, СПбГУ и т.д. - там по точным и естественным наукам дают образование часто лучше, чем заграницей.

Судя по всему, у Вас нет высшего образования (может, я ошибаюсь). Без этого с Вами никто нигде в научных кругах даже разговаривать не будет.

**P.S.** Еще немного подумал. На самом деле. работа на стыке науки и IT - это очень интересно и перспективно. Но для начала нужно получить фундаментальное образование либо в том, либо в другом. Так что, автору как раз по возрасту определиться, что его больше влечет, и туда и идти. Для поступления в ВУЗ, что на Родине, что заграницей, главное не профессиональный опыт, а способность хорошо сдать вступительные экзамены + язык (если ехать за бугор).

Comment: Цукерберг - Гарвард
Дуров -СПбГУ

Comment: А какое вообще отношение имеют всякие цукерманы к науке и научным задачам?

Comment: вы что антисемит=) по-моему большенство нобелевских лауреатов цукерманы

Comment: @Spectre, намекаете, что создание популярного сайтика достойно нобелевки? Я семит, кстати.

Comment: привёл пример достожений выпускников вышесказанных ВУЗов, не более того, `upd:` что говорит о качестве образования, о котором и говорил тов. @mikillskegg

Comment: @Spectre, это возращает нас к изначальному вопросу - какое отношение они имеют к науке и научным задачам? Очевидно, что выпускник СПбГУ способен скопировать некий популярный сайтик...

Comment: скопировать конечно это не проблема, но поддерживать и развивать это совсем другое дело. благо сайт-то процветает, будь он просто копией давно бы уже загнулся.

Answer (score 1):

Если хочется что-либо моделировать и визуализировать в части науки, можно начать с простого: волновый процессы, такие как дифракция и интерференция; фундаментальные взаимодействия, типа гравитационного и электромагнитного; рисование линий индукции магнитного поля и т.п. Я предложил из физики, но конечно есть и из других областей науки, хотя мне кажется это самое простое.

Answer (score 1):

Я получил учёную степень кандидата сельскохозяйственных наук, написав программу для сельскохозяйственных задач. Приходите к нам в лабораторию, работу для Вас найдём. Уехавшие за рубеж сотрудники у нас тоже есть, один в Америку, другой в Голландию

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется интересного научного/околонаучного программирования, можете озаботится проблемами искусственного интеллекта.

Попробуйте, например, начать с теста Тьюринга;)